# How to compare date from database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I would like to compare the date selected from the database (every entry in EndDate) and compare them with today date. Is there any way to do this programmatically? Like extracting the dates and comparing them individually? I need this because I need to update the status for the table.

```
string username;
username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
txtDate.Text = date;


SqlConnection conn1 = 
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=mydatasource\\sqlexpress;" 
                     + "Initial Catalog = Suite2; Integrated Security =SSPI");
SqlDataAdapter adapter;
string end;
end = "SELECT EndDate FROM Table_Message WHERE username = '" + username + "'";
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(end, conn1);
conn1.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
//Execute the sql command
GridView2.DataSource = ds;
GridView2.DataBind();
conn1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just modify the SQL query to do the comparison there rather than in code.

Replace your SQL with this.

```
end = "SELECT EndDate, " +
      "case when EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then 'Expired' " +
      "when StartDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then 'Pending' " +
      "else 'NotExpired' " +
      "end " +
      "as MessageStatus " +
      "FROM Table_Message WHERE username = '" + username + "'";
```

This should return two columns. One of EndDate and the other of whether it is before or after today.

EDIT

I realised that you want to update a table in the database not just return it. In that case you will need to execute a sql statement to update the appropriate columns and then select them. For example

```
 SqlCommand updateDatabase = new SqlCommand();
 updateDatabase.CommandText = "update dbo.Table_Message set Message_Status = case when EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then 'Expired' when StartDate <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP then 'Pending' else 'NotExpired'";
 updateDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You can then just select the status directly from your original query sql string

```
end = "SELECT EndDate, Message_Status " +
      "FROM Table_Message WHERE username = '" + username + "'";
```

Having said that. I would very strongly suggest you shouldn NOT be doing it this way. You should not be updating/storing something like the current status in the database. Each time you do the update in your case, you will be doing a very expensive database operation. Not only that, the meaning of the column changes every second, every millisecond. What is an "Expired" message really depends on the day you check. This sort of data should NOT be stored in the database. You should be interpreting which message is expired or and which is not each time. You can do that in C# code or as part of the SQL query like I originally suggested. You should not have a column in your database whose values can potentially change every second. That is my opinion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to make it if the EndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Update MessageStatus as "Expired"?

Comment: I have updated the SQL appropriately. You will have two columns now. One called EndDate and the other called MessageStatus.

Comment: Hey thanks!! Appreciated. But there isn't any error running the page but the MessageStatus didn't update ! >.<

Comment: Possible to throw in StartDate as well? Like comparing if smaller than startdate then pending, else if enddate smaller than Current_TIMESTAMP then expired, else ongoing.

Comment: Updated the SQL accordingly. You can add more conditions yourself and figure out the order of importance as well (For example if the begin date is after today, but end date is before today, do you want it 'Expired' or 'Pending'. Once again, I hope you don't have a column that you update every time by running this query. You should do this in code or in sql when querying or if you don't want to use the same database for multiple applications, create a view.

Answer (score 1):

```
   end = "UPDATE Table_Message SET message_status=CASE WHEN EndDate>GETDATE() then 'Expired' WHEN StartDate<GETDATE() then 'Pending' else 'Ongoing' END WHERE username = '" + username + "'";
```

Comment: Can I throw in StartDate as well? Something like this

                            mySQL = "UPDATE Table_Message SET MessageStatus=CASE WHEN EndDate<GETDATE() then 'Expired' else StartDate<GETDATE() then 'Pending' else 'Ongoing' END WHERE username = '" + username + "'";

Comment: Thank you very much !! Appreciate everything and everyone's help ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the date from the database.

```
DateTime dat1 = DateTime.Parse(2003-12-30); 
DateTime dat2 = DateTime.Parse(2004-12-30); 

TimeSpan spanTime=(dat1-dat2);
```

you can use `SpanTime` for comparison, like `spanTime.Days`.

Comment: I already get the date from Database by selecting it. How to do your method in code? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: What's code ? You just replace("2003-12-30") with your selected Date

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid. So for my case would be     DateTimedat1=DateTime.Parse(End); ?

Comment: DateTime dat1 = DateTime.Parse(End); 
DateTime dat2 = DateTime.Parse(Today Date);

Comment: And there will be more than one date in the database. This method will compare every single information or only the first one? Sorry ><

Comment: for(int i=0;i<count-1;i++){compare}

Answer (score 0):

**My opinion**

First if all. Are you going to use this code on client side or server side. You can compare the dates on sql server query also using datediff function. That way you will get exact comparision if the server and client clocks are not synchronized and you are planning to do it on client

Comment: I tried creating a job in SQL-server but for don't know what reason, my SQL-server's job agent disabled the "Schedule type" making me unable to select it to update the database daily. That's why I'm using coding method. The code will be used on the client side.

Comment: I am hoping that you are trying to retrieve the select then do some job for a time lapse and then update the table. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. I'm actually comparing the information then update it to another column for the MessageStatus

Comment: Fine, Now see you can always use the sql server date in your query like you can make an insert statement directly or using commandbuilder as {Insert into (Fld_Dt1)values(getdate())} or in update case {Update <TableName> set Fld_Dt1=case when Fld_dt1<=getdate()then getdate() else Fld_dt1 end} or the other way like >=